# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I have browsed many related topics and tried different ways, but the error is still there. Environment: Spring data jpa, Hibernate, maven, tomcat7

**Error Stack:**

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>   SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': **Injection of autowired dependencies failed**; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: **Could not autowire field: private com.zzz.service.UserService com.zzz.controller.UserController.userService**; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: **No qualifying bean of type [com.zzz.service.UserService] found for dependency**: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at 
>       ...

**applicationContext.xml**

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ... ... >
<context:component-scan base-package="com.zzz">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zzz" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.zzz.entity" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>

 <jpa:repositories base-package="com.zzz.repository" />
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ... ... >
<context:component-scan base-package="com.zzz.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="static/" />

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/defs/templates.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

**UserController.java**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/users")
    public String users(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("users", userService.findAll());
        return "users";
    }
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

**UDPATE 1**

There are 2 autowired errors:

Could not autowire field: **private com.zzz.repository.UserRepository com.zzz.service.UserService.userRepository**

could not autowire field: **private com.zzz.service.UserService com.zzz.controller.UserController.userService**

**UPDATE 2**

I've tried to use servlet-dispatcher.xml as the only configuration file (put the content of applicationContext.xml into it), it works fine. So it's the problem between these 2 xml files, but I couldn't tell it.

**UPDATE 3**

I renamed applicationContext.xml to root-context.xml, and set the contextConfigLocation to it in web.xml, the error disappeared!

It seems to be some configuration error about the applicationContext.xml, anybody could help?

Comment: What happens if you omit the exclude-filter?  i.e.  `<context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />`

Comment: the same error, thanks.

Comment: @user4076806 it also doesn't work, and it's not logical :)

Comment: what is not logical?

Comment: @frankzIs there any UserRepositoryImpl class or JPARepositoryImpl class defined at your system.

Comment: @erhun No implemetations.

Comment: @erhun I've tried this way, added a UserRepositoryImpl class, but the error hasn't changed. And I think Spring Data Jpa should build the repository implementation automatically.

Comment: I didn't say add Impl class i mean how this JPA classes declared as a bean.

Comment: @erhun Sorry I misunderstood, there's UserRepositoryImpl.class in the target directory.

Comment: Thanks for everyone, I've got the solution, but still not clear of the reason, please see my "UPDATE" above.

Answer (score 0):

another guess: in the dispatcher xml you only scan for the controller package...so if the application.xml is not loaded it does not scan the service package and thus the user service is not loaded... would be interesting what happens if you scan for the entire com.zzz package in the dispatcher.xml